# SQL - flag to only show data between 4PM yesterday and 4PM today

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssas, dax

hopefully someone can help with this. I have an SSAS cube in which I want to add a calculated column which I will use to filter data in Power BI.

The field I am working with is called "date created" (datetime data type)

I basically want a flag that I can use to only show data from 4PM onwards - for example, if a user viewed the report at 8am today, it would show them data from 4PM yesterday up until 8am today. If the user viewed it at 5:30pm today it would show data from 4PM today up until 5:30pm today - does that make sense? It would be as if 4pm was the start of a new day.

Thank you for any help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I asume you want this done automatically? i would make a calculated field and try working with the TODAY() option or the NOW() option. you can do a DAX notation as well and try to make a measure that will take 4:00PM as start date untill 4:00PM is pasted in the next day then take that 4:00PM (if-statement)

if this is not what you're looking for let me know then i'll try to figure out something else for you!

Comment: Hi, yes I would want this done automatically. So for example if the user looks at the report at 8PM, it will show them data from 4PM-8PM that same day. If they look at it at 7AM it will show them data from 4PM the previous day up until 7AM. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it certainly does!

i think this could be done with some DAX notations or by introducing a custom-table in query editor and making a if-statement that checks for every date if 4PM has passed or not. if it did then take that 4PM else take the 4PM time from the previous date.

does this help you?

Comment: I was looking to do it in DAX if this would be easier?

Comment: I think if you only would DAX this would still be possible. try making an if-statement which contain CALCULATE() in there so it can calculate the statement. as i said try searching some information on DAX - NOW() and TODAY()

Comment: Hi, I already have some calculated columns using NOW and TODAY I just wasn't sure how I would use these to achieve what i wanted..

Comment: maybe try using the TIME() module in combination with TODAY()

for example; if NOW() > TIME(4,0,0) & NOW () < TIME(28,0,0), <expresion>, <else-expresion>

you might need to combine the TIME() with TODAY() for the date

did this help you?

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and can't get it to do what I need.

Comment: What would you like to happen with the data thats older than the last 4PM ? would you want that to be historical or just be ignored?

Comment: Hi, it would be ignored. It should always only show data from 4PM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170217/discussion-between-rick-van-der-horst-and-jd8766).